# Metric spaces and norm spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

> If norm spaces can be turned into metric spaces, then why does a distinction between the  >two exist?

Comment: Because a metric space might not have a norm.....

Comment: Because it doesn't work the other way: not every metric is induced by norm

Comment: Just to add to the absolutely correct answers: Even though not every metric space is a normed space, every metric space can be isometrically (and canonically) embedded in a Banach space.

Comment: @studiosus: How so? There's the Kuratowski embedding, but this is not entirely canonical. In any case, when pointing out something like this, it wouldn't hurt to drop the name of the theorem or a short sketch.

Comment: @tomasz: Sorry, I forgot to say that the metric space $M$ is bounded. The embedding is $f(x)=d(x, \cdot)$ from $M$ to the space of bounded functions on $M$ with sup-norm. The embedding is called Kuratowski–Wojdysławski.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is necessary for a normed space to be a vector space, but a metric space need not be one. In fact, as the comments suggest, all normed spaces are metric but not vice versa. For a metric vector space $(V(\mathbb{F},d)$ to be normed, the metric has to satisfy two additional properties:

1. $d(x,y)=d(x+a,y+a)$ for all $a \in V$
2. $d(\alpha x,\alpha y) = |\alpha|d(x,y)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$

e.g. Consider the set $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and let us give it the discrete metric i.e. $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x \neq y$ and $0$ else. Note that this is not a vector space. How can you define a norm then?

Answer (score 1):

There are metric spaces that aren't vector spaces, so they can't have a norm.

Not even every metric vector space is a normed space, or even equivalent to one. The classic examples are the $\ell^p$ spaces for $0<p<1$, which have no nonzero continuous linear functionals. Normed spaces have lots of continuousl linear functionals by the Hahn–Banach theorem.